# How to print the JSON array data into the UILabel in Swift3 at new lines

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3

I have got a JSON response like this:

```
[
    {
        "days": [
            "Sun",
            "Mon",
            "Tue",
            "Wed",
            "Thu"
        ],
        "times": [
            "09:00-12:00",
            "16:00-21:00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "days": [
            "Fri"
        ],
        "times": [
            "17:00-22:00"
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I have got a UILabel in which I am setting the text of days and times into next lines. The UILabel text will be looking like:

Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu

09:00-12:00

16:00-21:00

Fri

17:00 - 22:00

For this i am using the code :

```
var allDays = ""
var allTimes = ""
var allDaysTimes = ""
for operating in shop.operatingDays! {
  print(operating.days ?? "")
  print(operating.times ?? "")
  for days in operating.days! {
    print(days)
    allDays.append(days)
   // cell.operationalDays.text = allDays
  }
  for times in operating.times! {
    print(times)
    allTimes.append(times + "\n") 
    allDaysTimes = allDays + "\n" + allTimes
  }
  cell.operationalDays.text = allDaysTimes + "\n"
}
```

But i am not able to print Fri to the next line but it is showing in the same line along with Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu
Any idea how to acheive

Comment: `let v = arrayJSON.flatMap( {(subDict)  -> String in let days = subDict["days"]?.joined(separator: " "); let times = subDict["times"]?.joined(separator: "\n"); return days! + "\n" + times! }).joined(separator: "\n"); cell.operationalDays.text = v;`?

Comment: @ChelseaShawra you have only one UI LAbel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var allDays = ""
var allTimes = ""
var allDaysTimes = ""
for operating in shop.operatingDays! {
  print(operating.days ?? "")
  print(operating.times ?? "")
  for days in operating.days! {
    print(days)
    allDays.append(days)
   // cell.operationalDays.text = allDays
  }

  for times in operating.times! {
    print(times)
    allTimes.append(times + "\n") 

  }
  allDaysTimes.append(allDays + "\n" + allTimes)
  allDays = "\n"
  allTimes = ""

}
cell.operationalDays.text = allDaysTimes
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
for operating in shop.operatingDays! {
    print(operating.days ?? "")
    print(operating.times ?? "")
    cell.operationalDays.text =  operating.days!.joined() + operating.times.joined() + "\n"
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?